# Vim Latex Suite: Display inline-math delimiters ($$)

Tags: vim, latex

As the title suggests: The Latex Suite for VIM (VIMLatex) doesn't display inline-math delimiters ($$) sometimes as I'm typing in that particular line. However, I'd like to show them.
What I currently see when typing:

```
BLABLA: \omega = 2\, \pi\, f
```

What I'd like to have:

```
BLABLA: $ \omega = 2\, \pi\, f $
```

I already searched the documentation but could not find the setting…

Comment: This has nothing to do with vim-latexsuite, it is a feature of vim own syntax file for LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should display them while typing in the current line. Search your vimrc for a line that adjusts `concealcursor` (short: `cocu`) option, it should not contain `i`, also check `verbose set cocu?`.

You can disable concealing completely by adding

```
set conceallevel=0
```

to your vimrc.

Comment: `concealcursor` contained `i` - thanks. Did it very fine and saved me some time of searching!
For all others: add this to your .vimrc:
`set concealcursor=`

Comment: @Vincent It is the default setting (I mean, empty `concealcursor`). No need to add this to the vimrc, just remove other sets.